# Update the data in one component based on what is clicked in another component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components let's call them CompA and CompB.  I would like for the clicked item object in CompA to appear in CompB.  Here is what I have done so far.

### CompA:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CompB} from './compB';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp-a',
    template: '<ul>
                   <li *ngFor="#item of items" (click)="show(item)">
                       {{item.name}}
                   </li>
               </ul>',
    providers: [CompB]
})
export class CompA {
    constructor(public _compB: CompB){}

    show(item){
        this._compB.displayItem(item);
    }
}
```

### CompB:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'comp-b',
    template: '<div>
                  {{item.name}}
               </div>'
})
export class CompB {
    public newItem: Object;

    constructor(){
        this.newItem = {name: "TEST"};
    }

    displayItem(item){
        this.newItem = item;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click an item it doesn't change anything in CompB.  I did a console log on CompB and I am getting the item object just fine but I view doesn't update with the clicked item's name.  It just stays as 'TEST'.

Even if I set this.newItem in the displayItem function to a hardcoded string, it still doesn't change.

### Update:

Both components are siblings in a main.html like this...

### main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <comp-a></comp-a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <comp-b></comp-b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the Component B you got injected in the constructor is not the component B used in the application. Its another component B that the hierarchical injector created, when Component B was added to the list of providers.

One way to do it is to create a separate injectable service, and inject it in both components. One component subscribes to the service and the other triggers a modification. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

    private items = new Subject(); 

    newItem(item) {
        this.subject.next(item);
    }
}
```

This needs to be configured in the bootstrap of the Angular 2 app:

```
boostrap(YourRootComponent, [ItemsService, ... other injectables]);
```

And then inject it on both components. Component A sends new items:

```
export class CompA {
    constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService){}

    show(item){
        this.itemsService.newItem(item);
    }
}
```

And component B subscribes to new items:

```
export class CompB {
    constructor(itemsService: ItemsService){
        itemsService.items.subscribe((newItem) => {
            //receive new item here
        });
    }
```

Have a look at the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html), as its useful to consume observables in the template directly.

Comment: Interesting, is this what needs to be done every time you want to communicate between components?  There needs to be a injectable service that talks to the entire app?

Comment: This is one way of doing it using Observables, if the components are on the same view and are siblings we can also inject some components into others using `@Host` or `@ContentChildren` etc., but that is recommended for components that are tightly coupled, like a list and its items. If we want to decouple the components, Observables works well.

Comment: I looked at applying this but there were some errors.  What is Subject?  this.subject cannot be resolved.  Is that coming from an import?  In component B how are you using items in the constructor?  All these errors came up with those two.  Please advise.

Comment: here are some more details on RxJs subjects -> https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.mdyou can import it using `import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject"`

Comment: Page not found when I click on the link.

Comment: Can you add a plunkr so I can see it in motion pls.  That would help me better understand.

Comment: Also, if you set items to private in the ItemsService class then you cannot access it in the CompB class because it is private.  I changed it to public and that error went away but I still keep getting that there is no ItemsService provider for CompA and CompB Component.  If I add them as providers then it will create a new provider for each one which is what we don't want.

Comment: you can inject ItemsService in any class you need it, so need to call it from one class to the other. for the no provider, i'll adapt the answer, you need to configure to be injected, thats what no provider found means. The best is to inject it in the root of the application via bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `CompB` instance passed to

```
constructor(public _compB: CompB){}
```

it's not the instance you expect but a different (new) one.

There are different strategies to communicate between components. This depends on how they are related in the view. Are they siblings, parent and child or something else. Your question doesn't provide this information.

For parent and child you can use data binding with inputs and outputs.

For siblings you can use data binding if you include the common parent (use it as mediator)

You always can use a shared service.

For data-binding details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: What is the strategy if the components are not related by a parent-child nor a sibling relationship?

Comment: Use a shared service like explained by @jhadesdev