# How do I set the value of a property of a Component from a different Component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Although I have no compiler errors and Intellisense is completing the different Components the data just doesn't get set in the view.

**app.component.ts**

```
onSelect(item: TodoItem) {
  this.SelectItemComponent.selectedItem = { Name: 'name', Key: 'key' };
}
```

**select-item.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedItem = { Name: 'Name', Key: 'Key' };
}
```

the `ngOnInit()` in `select-item.component.ts` sets the value of the view correctly, but `selectedItem` set from `app.component.ts` doesn't update the view.

**Full code:**
**app.component.ts**

```
import { Inject, Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { TodoItem } from './TodoItem';
import { AddItemComponent } from './add-item.component';
import { SelectItemComponent } from './select-item.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [
        AddItemComponent,
        SelectItemComponent
    ],
    templateUrl: 'templates/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    private items: Array<TodoItem> = new Array<TodoItem>();
    private selectedItem: TodoItem;
    public SelectItemComponent: SelectItemComponent;

    constructor( @Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.collection$.subscribe(latestCollection => {
            this.items = latestCollection;
        });
        this.dataService.getItems();
    }

    onSelect(item: TodoItem) {
        this.SelectItemComponent.selectedItem = { Name: item.Name, Key:      item.Key };
    }
}
```

**select-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from 'angular2/core';
import { TodoItem } from './TodoItem';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'select-item',
    templateUrl: 'templates/select-item.html'
})

export class SelectItemComponent {
    public selectedItem: TodoItem;
    public collection$: Observable<Array<TodoItem>>;
    private _collectionObserver: any;
    private _collection: Array<TodoItem>;

    constructor(@Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.selectedItem = { Name: 'Name', Key: 'Key' };
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this answer, its one way to do it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093864/update-the-data-in-one-component-based-on-what-is-clicked-in-another-component-i/35094087#35094087

Comment: How are these two components related? Is one of them a child of another? Also, where is `AppComponent.SelectItemComponent` initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks loose11 !!)) I found @Input() broke Angular 2 Beta 2 although I haven't tried it with a callback which I'm going to do). This code works using:

```
inputs: ['selectedItem: item'],
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Inject, Component, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { TodoItem } from './TodoItem';
import { AddItemComponent } from './add-item.component';
import { SelectItemComponent } from './select-item.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [
        AddItemComponent,
        SelectItemComponent
    ],
    templateUrl: 'templates/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    private items: Array<TodoItem> = new Array<TodoItem>();
    item: TodoItem;

    constructor(@Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.collection$.subscribe(latestCollection => {
            this.items = latestCollection;
        });
        this.dataService.getItems();
        this.item = { Name: '', Key: '' };
    }

    onSelect(item: TodoItem) {
            this.item = { Name: item.Name, Key: item.Key };
        }
    }
```

**select-item-component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import { TodoItem } from './TodoItem';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'select-item',
    inputs: ['selectedItem: item'],
    templateUrl: 'templates/select-item.html'
})

export class SelectItemComponent {
    public collection$: Observable<Array<TodoItem>>;
    private _collectionObserver: any;
    private _collection: Array<TodoItem>;

    constructor(@Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) { }

}
```

**app.html** needs this code

```
<select-item [item]="item"></select-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the **select-item.component** is a component of the **app.component** you can communicate between them with *@Input* and *@Output*. The angular docs describe it very well. The [*@Output*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Output-var.html) is for the communication up to the parent and the [*@Input*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html) from parent to child.

In your case you need the @Output in your **select-item.component** and a callback at the **app.component**.

For example:

**select-item.component.ts**

```
export class SelectItemComponent {
  @Output() callback:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public selectedItem: TodoItem;


  constructor(@Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.callback.emit({ Name: 'Name', Key: 'Key' });
  }
}
```

For the Callback you don't need to touch the app.component, only the html template to set the callback for the child.

```
<select-item (callback)="onSelect($event)"></select-item>
```

No if the select-item trigger the callback, the app get a notification and updated the values

Comment: Your solution seems a lot simpler although I couldn't follow the <app (callback)="onSelect($event)"></app>

Comment: Oh sorry it have to be select-item. I edited it :-) If the answer is right please accept it.

Comment: Hi loose11 thanks for that I'll try it out and mark as answer when I succeed)